# Forcing a serial compilation on make for R package

Tags: r, makefile, rcpp, r-package

I submitted a package to CRAN ([sundialr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sundialr/index.html)) around 6 months back which was recently archived as it fails with the parallel version of `make`. The exact error message from one of CRAN maintainers is as follows

> This have just failed to install for me with a parallel make:
>
> ```
> g++ -std=gnu++98 -std=gnu++98 -shared 
> -L/data/blackswan/ripley/extras/lib64 -L/usrlocal/lib64 -o sundialr.so 
> cvode.o RcppExports.o -L/data/blackswan/ripley/R/R-patched/lib -lRlapack 
> -L/data/blackswan/ripley/R/R-patched/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm 
> -lquadmath -L../inst/ ../inst/libsundials_all.a
> g++: error: ../inst/libsundials_all.a: No such file or directory
> make[1]: *** [/data/blackswan/ripley/R/R-patched/share/make/shlib.mk:6: 
> sundialr.so] Error 1
> ```
>
> The library was still being made ....

It seems the package fails to generate the static library with the parallel make. The easiest solution I could think of for this problem was to force a serial version of `make` using the `.NOTPARALLEL` phony command in `Makevars` and `Makevars.win` (https://github.com/sn248/sundialr/blob/master/src/Makevars). I have made this change and it seems to work on my machine and on testing on `TravisCI` and `Appveyor` (https://github.com/sn248/sundialr).

However, before I re-submit to CRAN, I wanted to get an opinion as to will this be enough to get rid of error with parallel make? Sorry for cross-posting on `r-package-devel`, it seems my email to the list yesterday did not get to the forum.

Comment: I am an r-package-devel co-admin, and I did not a bounce. Subscribe, and make sure you email from the exact same address.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I was indeed emailing from a different address. I have re-sent my message. Hopefully, it will get posted to the forum successfully.

Comment: There is some stuff in _Writing R Extensions_ about parallel `make` and targets.  You could punt and build the static library from `configure` ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The guide does state  -_Be careful to create all the necessary dependencies, as there is no guarantee that the dependencies of all will be run in a particular order (and some of the CRAN build machines use multiple CPUs and parallel makes)_  I do not want to sound lazy but for a large external library (from which some of the files are used here), creating that dependency tree sounds like a lot of work and really understanding what is going on in the third party code .. would forcing a serial make not work, since it builds on a single build machine..

Comment: Your dependencies are probably not complete. For instance, you did not tell make that `sundialr.so` depends on `../inst/libsundials_all.a`. In most cases telling make what the dependencies are is not more difficult than telling it what to do: if you have a recipe that looks like `BUILD -o OUPUT INPUTS`, then the dependencies are just `OUPUT: INPUTS` (and, incidentally, you can use [make automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to simplify your recipe: `BUILD -o $@ I$^`).

Comment: I find this really odd. You have `($SHLIB): $(OBJECTS) ../inst/libsundials_all.a` in your [`Makevars`](https://github.com/sn248/sundialr/blob/dbb40e076e6f0576e52cf0a135e29c6b49799c89/src/Makevars#L69), so why does `make` try to build `sundialr.so` before the static library is finished?

Comment: @RalfStubner - Thank you. This happens only with parallel `make` as mentioned in CRAN message, but I agree, I am not sure why `sundialr.so` is built before the static file is finished making. I think `($SHLIB): $(OBJECTS) ../inst/libsundials_all.a` does imply that the static library is a dependency for the shared object, so this target should be built after making the library even in the parallel version. Any thoughts about `.NOTPARALLEL:` phony target usage?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - Thank you for your comment. Does `($SHLIB): $(OBJECTS) ../inst/libsundials_all.a` not specify that `libsundials_all.a` is a dependency for the `sundialr.so`?

Comment: @RalfStubner - Another quick question, hope you can help, is there any way to test the `r` package build with parallel `make` (i.e., locally or using `rhub` etc.)? Thank you.

Comment: @SN248: If there is a make variable named `S` and its value is `FOO`, `($SHLIB)` is expanded by make as `(FOOHLIB)`, that is not `sundialr.so`. And if there is no make variable named `S` or its value is the empty string, `($SHLIB)` expands as `(HLIB)`, not `sundialr.so` neither. So, no, this cannot declare the missing dependency. Maybe should it be `$(SHLIB)`, but even then, you should also have a make variable named `SHLIB` somewhere (I could not find it) and its value should be `sundialr.so`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I think the miss-placed parenthesis is the solution! `$(SHLIB)` is defined by R's build environment.

Comment: For testing parallel make you can set the environment variable `MAKEFLAGS` to `-j 2`, c.f. https://github.com/coatless/sitmo/blob/ea425902f15baf90e92628dd6cf60795d963b833/.travis.yml#L7.

Comment: @RalfStubner Thank you for your hint regarding `$(SHLIB)` and `MAKEFLAGS`. It is very interesting that while `$(SHLIB)` in `Makevars` works, on Windows, i.e., for `Makevars.win`, `$(SHLIB)` gives me linking errors, but `($SHLIB)` works fine and even passes `CRAN` checks. Very odd!

Comment: The linking error on Windows is odd. However, `$(SHLIB)` is documented, so this might warrant a new question.