# Odd SHLIB behavior while compiling and linking an R package with cpp code

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I am compiling an R package containing `.cpp` source files from a third party. To compile the `.cpp` files into a static library, I am using the `Makevars.win` file ([link](https://github.com/sn248/sundialr/blob/master/src/Makevars.win)). I stumbled upon an odd behavior of `SHLIB` on Windows only, while trying to fix another problem related to parallel `make` which revealed that I had a misplaced parenthesis defining `$(SHLIB)` as `($SHLIB)` in `Makevars` and `Makevars.win` files ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137171/forcing-a-serial-compilation-on-make-for-r-package)).

Long story short, I had written `$(SHLIB)` incorrectly as `($SHILB)` in my `Makevars` and `Makevars.win` files. Correcting that mistake gives me no error on `Linux` and `OSX` machines, but on Windows `($SHLIB)` works, but `$(SHLIB)` gives me the following error:

```
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_bandpre_impl.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_bbdpre_impl.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_diag_impl.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_direct_impl.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_impl.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_spils_impl.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_bandpre.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_bbdpre.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_diag.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_direct.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_impl.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: cvode_spils.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: fnvector_serial.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: nvector_serial.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_band.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_config.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_dense.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_direct.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_fconfig.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_fnvector.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_iterative.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_linearsolver.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_math.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_matrix.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_nvector.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_pcg.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_sparse.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_spbcgs.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_spfgmr.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_spgmr.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_sptfqmr.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_types.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sundials_version.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: fsunlinsol_dense.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sunlinsol_band.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sunlinsol_dense.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sunlinsol_pcg.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sunlinsol_spbcgs.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sunlinsol_spfgmr.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sunlinsol_spgmr.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sunlinsol_sptfqmr.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: fsunmatrix_dense.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: fsunmatrix_band.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sunmatrix_band.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sunmatrix_dense.h: File format not recognized
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\nm.exe: sunmatrix_sparse.h: File format not recognized
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o sundialr.dll tmp.def cvode.o RcppExports.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64 -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L../inst/ -lsundials_all -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
../inst//libsundials_all.a(cvode_bandpre.o):cvode_bandpre.c:(.text+0x679): undefined reference to `SUNBandLinearSolver'
../inst//libsundials_all.a(cvode_bandpre.o):cvode_bandpre.c:(.text+0x360): undefined reference to `SUNLinSolSetup_Band'
../inst//libsundials_all.a(cvode_bbdpre.o):cvode_bbdpre.c:(.text+0x819): undefined reference to `SUNBandLinearSolver'
../inst//libsundials_all.a(cvode_bbdpre.o):cvode_bbdpre.c:(.text+0x2ea): undefined reference to `SUNLinSolSetup_Band'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'sundialr'
```

I understand the `undefined reference` error messages are linking errors, but I am not sure why I am getting the `File format not recognized` error messages for header files. More interestingly, why it all works fine with substituting `$(SHLIB)` with `($SHLIB)` in the `Makevars.win` file when the WRE document talks about `$(SHLIB)` and not  `($SHLIB)`. In fact, the package passed all CRAN checks and was on CRAN till very recently with `($SHLIB)` in `Makevars.win`.

Can any one explain why this is happening and how can I resolve the errors I am getting with `$(SHLIB)` now. I would like to replace the erroneous `($SHLIB)` in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SOURCES_*` variables have a mixture of `.c` and `.h` files. The `.c` are replaces with `.o` for `OBJECTS_SUNDIALS_ALL`, but the `.h` files stay in. These seem to confuse `nm.exe` when building the static library. If you remove the `.h` files from the `SOURCES_*` variables, the `File format not recognized` messages should go away.

Comment: Thank you so much Ralf! Indeed removing the header files made those errors go away. I was also able to resolve the linking errors by including a source file in `/src` sub-folder which I was missing before. You are so very helpful!

Comment: To anyone else reading this post - I still don't understand why it all worked with `($SHLIB)`, so any explanation will be much appreciated!